# Change direction but not affecting force

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im struggling with this, tried adding force but its not working the way I wanted, tried also changing direction but it changes by 45degrees which in my case is not what I wanted. Im thinking about adding the wind zone in the direction of arrwos, but came here to ask if theres any other(better) way to do it. Any help would be great! Thanks and have a great day!

[Heres image for easier understainding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8m6zZ.png)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ArrowGrass : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody ball;
    public float arrowPower;
    public float stoppingPower;
    private void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)
    {
        

        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            Vector3 direction = ball.velocity.normalized;
            float speed = ball.velocity.magnitude;
            Vector3 currentVelocity = ball.velocity;
            Vector3 desiredDirection = new Vector3(-1, 0, 0); // set this to the direction you want.
            Vector3 newVelocity = desiredDirection.normalized * currentVelocity.magnitude;
            ball.AddForce(newVelocity - currentVelocity, ForceMode.VelocityChange);


            /*
            ball.angularDrag = stoppingPower;
            Debug.Log("Colided");
            ball.AddForce(new Vector3(-1, 0, 0) * arrowPower * stoppingPower, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
            */
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO: please post your code

Comment: You'd need to add a constant force to get it to push it gradually.

Comment: The angle is the y/x which is the ball speed/wind speed.

Comment: Thanks for welcome! Here I edited the post and added code.@auburg

So instead of addforce, addconstantforce?@TEEBQNE

Comment: Check out the different force modes: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ForceMode.html Some are instant, some are continuous.

Comment: @jdweng picture is alike bird perspective, so its x and z axis, will be depended on map level. The only thing I need help with is to keep force from the ball, so its like goin normally forward, but when enters the arrowGrass area it should be gradually pushed to the left side also keeping forward direction(picture scenario 2)). And also should be able to stop when force is done.

Comment: @KYL3R but with adding force ball should not be able to stop in area of arrows? am I right?And Im also affecting the force that was added before to push ball at the first place?

Comment: You need a friction force of the surface.  Going through air will be different from grass and will be in the opposite direction of the wind.

Comment: I think you should create a separate variable for the user-force that gradually shrinks to 0 (to fake friction). Then, you can add external forces like the conveyor belt or wind etc. and still check if the user-force is 0, to allow the player to shoot again.

Comment: Hm, understood. Can you give me example in code?

Answer (score 0):

Separate the Forces.

```
private float userForce = 0f;
void FixedUpdate()
{
    if(userForce > 0.1f) // define a minimum force, as we won't reach actual 0.
    { 
        userForce *= 0.95; // no need for Time.deltaTime as we are in FixedUpdate!  
    }else{
        // we can shoot again. User-Force has ended.
        userForce = 0; // just make it stop completely eventually.
    }
    rb.AddForce(userForce * velocity * direction); // you have to define velocity and direction.
}
```

The OnTriggerStay logic is on the conveyor belt itself, where you can define the force strenght and direction. It is applied to the Physx system and affects the players Rigidbodies velocity. But we can track our userforce whilst ignoring other forces. So the ball can continue to move or at least get pushed to a wall etc.

In the end you can just apply the same principle to a timer as well. Either checking timestamps, or just decreasing a variable using Time.deltaTime and checking if it's < 0.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. If that solved your problem, consider marking the Answer as accepted.